# How to pass context to a module classes without using a static context?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I have created a library, and added as a module in my app. My library does not have any `activity class`, all classes are core java classes, so i don't have access to `context`.

This is what i did;

- My library class is `singleton`
- I have created a static variable like this; `static Context myGlobalContext`
- I created a method where i set this context;

> ```
>  public void init(Context context){ 
>         myGlobalContext=context;
> }
> ```

I set this context from the first activity;

```
    MyClass.sharedInstance().init(MyApplication.getAppContext());
```

then i use this `myGlobalContext` in all of the library classes. 
This thing works fine when i debug this, the value of `myGlobalContext` is never null, but i am getting some crashes from crashlytics, where `context` is null.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.SharedPreferences
>   android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)'
>   on a null object reference

When i run `lint`, it also warns about the `static global context`

This is my `application class`, here i create context;

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
}

  public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyApplication.context;
    }
```

Comment: *I set this context from the first activity* and that's the problem ... **not always first activity will be really first** (obvious example 1. you are on second activity 2. you press home 3. after some time process get killed by OS 4. you return to second activity) ... why didn't you follow bet practices and have `MyClass.with(context).doSomething()` like fx picasso library do?

Comment: Thanks @Selvin, I understand your point, i will pass the context by using this way, but in module I have multiple classes that needs context

Comment: @Selvin : I am passing application level context, and not activity context

Comment: but not always ... obviously in second activity you are using this code without `init` ... so obviously init is never called ... so obviously you are getting NPE

Comment: @Selvin : what if i call `init` from the base application class which is extending from `application`. Does android keep it, or it also destroys it the base application class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
```

With

```
MyApplication.context = this;
```

And you need to add the application name to the manifest for this Context to ever be set

However, if you have a core Java library, you should not be using an Application because you have no life cycle methods to handle. Just define methods that use Context objects, import your library externally, and use Application Context sparingly if you're actually in an Activity, Service, or other Context subclass

Answer (score 1):

according to your code you should have at least one instance of MyApplication or just set some default data to MyApplication.context, then your static getAppContext will return some value